# How to keep my glasses clean from getting marks

Tags: cleaning, efficiency

It is really annoying to keep taking reading/driving glasses off to clean them and put them back on to know there is a new spot or new spot appear and there is at least one tissue going to waste every day.

How can I make sure my glasses are free from any mark and do not get any while learning (which I do not know how I get it)

Answer (score 10):

Dust and the occasional grease mark are inevitable. You can train yourself never to put your fingers on your glasses (only touch the frame), that reduces the number of grease marks.

Instead of disposable tissues, you could use the cleaning cloth that is often supplied with glasses, or a cloth handkerchief.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Nothing can't be clear always. Also, you can use a special liquid to clean your glasses

Answer (score 1):

I use a spray and then clean with a cloth. You can easily see the  fogged surface and clean up  without  leaving  any corner  untouched. It is important  the spray releases very small droplets - almost like a mist. Avoid computer screen sprays that are larger droplets. Get hold of a misty one.

Answer (score 0):

As noted the way to stop marks is to train yourself not yo touch the lenses.

To clean I rub them under a running water tap and dry with a cotton towel. It might be better to use a microfibre cloth for drying.

Answer (score 0):

You must only touch the frames and only the lenses by their edges. It is important to never clean the lenses with a dry cloth or tissue. Start with a spay or under the water with dish soap. Then you can use a cloth or even your fingers and dry with a clean cloth or let them dry in the air.